# richtextbox selectioncolor and selectionbackcolor property

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to select a particular line of text and highlight it with a Blue Color and i want the forecolor of that text to be white. 
I tried

```
 this.Select(start, length);
 this.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
 this.SelectionColor = Color.White;
```

but it doesn't work.
What is wrong?
I want to simulate the effect we get when we select some text through the mouse, where it's backcolor gets light blue and text inside gets white. I can get that by just doing

```
 this.Select(start, length);
```

but then as soon as it loses focus, the selection vanishes, i want it permanent.

Comment: I just tried, it works fine for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is more simple way to color text in richtextbox:

```
richtTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox.SelectedText = "Red text";
richtTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
richTextBox.SelectedText = "Green text";
```

And you get: 
[image]